# Using filed name from MYSQL database as a header column in API datatable dart

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

I make a table with Datatable flutter dart where getting data from API. It was successful done. Let MySQL have four field... "**id", "production", "2022", "2023**". I want to use field name "2022" and "2023" as a header column through getting field name not by typing "2022" in dart code. Because some day I want to change filed name "2022" and "2023" to be "2023" and "2024", and so the column header can change without I write again the code..  So I just change data and column name in `mysql` table and then the table become:

```
"id", "production", "2023", "2024"
```

Any suggestion or answer would be very appreciate.
(PS. Sorry for my English)

I want to change filed name "2022" and "2023" to be "2023" and "2024" and so the column header can change without I write again the code..  So I just change data and column name in `mysql` table and then the table become:

```
"id", "production", "2023", "2024"
```